# Submission and video related query using Xcode

Tags: url, video, webkit, quicktime

Des anyone know what is meant by this - I could understand if I was using a piece of media embedded but I'm viewing a quicktime file through the web using a webview so any clarification would be great?

1. main pages for videos are incorrectly formatted for iPhone

Thanks :-)

Comment: Although no one was able to shed any light on this and I have not received information from the resolution team, despite sending them a query, it seems that they were just in need of a URL sample for this.  So that was the solution - the format didn't need to be changed and remained as originally had been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They required that a sample URL was submitted - the video format was fine.  Hope this helps anyone with similar issue come back.